# How to remove substring from the string entered through "stdin" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input: Input consists of many lines. At the end of each line, there is a hash symbol #. 
For example:

```
1st line# 
2nd line# 
3rd line#
Output expected:
1st line 
2nd line
3rd line
```

Comment: If you have anything else than `#` in any line you will get stuck in an endless loop. What's the purpose of the `while`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

when this code is used, a new line character is appended internally to the line.
so first we can strip it using the rstrip(). Since the requirement is only to remove a '#' present as the last letter of the line, we can simply slice it.

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line.rstrip()[:-1])
```

Comment: Here also the same case , I'm not getting the output of 3rd line. Input : blah# 45 67# fjhg# Output : blah 45 67

Comment: This worked for me in all your 3 cases.Try to add a screenshot of your output. That may help to figure out the problem

Comment: Hi Sai Pratyusha, I have added the screensot to the question.

Comment: Hello Nikhil , thank you for adding the screen shot. I too am not sure why the last line is being ignored . But have you pressed enter after giving your last input line?

Comment: I was missing the enter after the last line. Now I have given enter. And that works. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You have loop when never will finish.. I don't see the need of while in your case.

```
  import sys
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.replace('#', '')
        print(line)
```

Comment: You could use `line.strip('#')` as well

Comment: blah#
45 67#
ddgfh fjhg gjkhgk#

blah



45 67  I'm not getting output of 3rd string of the input

Comment: I'm not sure  why you are not getting it .

Comment: @SashoRistovski Last line of my input is getting ignored by the code. 1st line#
2nd line#
3rd line#
4th line#1st line

2nd line

3rd line

Comment: @SashoRistovski Thanks for the code. It works after giving enter for the last line of input.